# Set a cookie inside the 404.php theme page

Tags: php

I'm trying to set a cookie with these code but the cookie is not created

```
setcookie( 'name', 'carl', 0, '/names', 'https://my.webdomain.com', isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]), true);
```

I was looking on the internet a possible solution and I found and try this solution

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse8170_init' );
function wpse8170_init() {
    if ( !headers_sent() ) {
        setcookie( 'name', 'carl', 0, '/names', 'https://my.webdomain.com', isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]), true);
    }
}
```

But it didn't work. Please help, I just need a way to create a cookie inside my 404.php theme page and then I will make a redirection to another page of my own website, as the cookie is just to keep the variable for the next page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the template files load too late, try setting it in the functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse325439_init' );
function wpse325439_init() {
    if ( !headers_sent() && is_404() ) {
        setcookie( 'name', 'carl', 0, '/names/', 'my.webdomain.com', isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]), true);
    }
}
```